# How to count the number of times text is repeated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data like

A
B
A
D
C
E
C
A

I want that when A is repeated I get the number of time(freqency) it gets repeated.
So data set should read like this
A 1
B 1
A 2
D 1
C 1
E 1
C 2
A 3

I need to know a formula which can help me identify the count beside the text and nth number of time it got repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is in column A. Put in Cell B1 and drag down:

```
=Countifs($A$1:$A1,A1)
```

Comment: I don't think this works. It will show me the count. I want it like when was the first time it got repeated, second time, third time...so on so the final result will be like if first time repeat then 1 second time 2 and so on

Comment: This does exactly that. It will provide the output you have listed last.